# Asynchronous api for obtaining GPS position in python for S60

Tags: python, position, pys60

I'm using positioning.position(). but this function is blocking.
I want to be able to run another function while the GPS is being measured.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the S60, but if it supports threading here's an example of doing two functions at once:

```
import threading
import time

def doit1():
    for i in range(10):
        time.sleep(.1)
        print 'doit1(%d)' % i

def doit2():
    for i in range(10):
        time.sleep(.2)
        print 'doit2(%d)' % i

t = threading.Thread(target=doit2)
t.start()
doit1()
t.join()
print 'All done.'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: what is the function of t.join?
if doit1 for exmple is the function that measures gps and doit2 is the UI function, How can I know that the GPS result parameter was assigned in the end of the measurement and can be accessed from the second function?

Comment: another thing, if I understood, this can be a simple way to implement timer? just by defining a function that "sleeps" for some time interval. Can I use more than 2 asynchronous functions in the solution you suggested? How can it be done?

Comment: @Day_Dreamer: t.join() waits in the main thread for t to exit.  For timers, there is a threading.Timer class.  You can also create and start more than one thread.  For fancier threads, subclass Thread.  See the docs: http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.5/library/threading.html#thread-objects